# $|b-a|=|b-c|+|c-a| \implies c\in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

We know that if $c\in [a,b]$ we have $|b-a|=|b-c|+|c-a|$. I'm trying to prove that if the norm is induced by an inner product, then the converse holds.

I need a hint or something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of mathematical objects are $a,b,c$? Are they real numbers? Or elements of a vector space? I think you have to explain a little more what you mean by an interval and an inner product to clarify what your question is.

Comment: @MarkBennet They are real numbers and $[a,b]$ is the usual closed interval in $\mathbb R$

Comment: And what do you mean by an inner product on the real numbers?

Comment: @MarkBennet I think every inner product on the real numbers are of this form: $\langle x,y \rangle=\lambda xy$, where $\lambda \gt 0$, am I right?

Comment: @Rob1.2 An inner product is determined by its action on pairs of vectors belonging to a basis and by the bilinearity; these inner products make a symmetric positive definite matrix and the full action is determined by bilinearity. In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, you can take $\{1\}$ as the basis, so the inner product is determined by $a=\langle1,1\rangle>0$ and then $\langle x,y\rangle=axy$.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it's true, thanks for point this out.

Answer (score 2):

I will prove that generally, in an inner product space $(H,\langle,\rangle)$ the equality
$$\Vert a-b\Vert=\Vert a-c\Vert+\Vert c-b\Vert$$
implies $c\in[a,b]$.

Indeed, let $x=b-c$, $y=c-a$, so that the hypothesis becomes $\Vert x+y\Vert=\Vert x\Vert+\Vert y\Vert$. Squaring and simplifying we get
$$
 \langle x,y\rangle=\Vert x\Vert\cdot\Vert y\Vert
$$
So
$$
\left\Vert \Vert y\Vert x-\Vert x\Vert y
\right\Vert^2= 2\Vert x\Vert^2\, \Vert y\Vert^2 -
2\Vert x\Vert\, \Vert y\Vert\langle x,y\rangle=0
$$ 
That is $\Vert y\Vert x-\Vert x\Vert y
 =0$. Going back to $a$, $b$ and $c$ this is equivalent to
$$
c=\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b \quad\hbox{with}\quad
\lambda=\frac{\Vert b-c\Vert}{\Vert a-b\Vert}.
$$
That is $c\in[a,b]$.$\qquad\square$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Do you know any counterexample if the norm is not induced by a inner product?

Comment: @Rob1.2 Try with the $\|{\cdot}\|_1$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @egreg I'm looking for a counterexample in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Rob1.2 In $\mathbb{R}$ *all* norms are induced by an inner product: if $\|{\cdot}\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\|x\|=|x|\,\|1\|$ and $\|1\|>0$; then the norm is induced by the inner product $(x,y)\mapsto\|1\|xy$.

Comment: @egreg The problem I think is you define the inner product using the norm itself, I don't think it's a right proof.

Comment: @Rob1.2 Sorry, but it's correct. If you have a norm on $\mathbb{R}$, you *know* the norm of $1$. That is the value used later.

Comment: But in order to prove the norm is induced by the inner product you have to prove $|x|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$. In your case you define the inner product using $\Vert 1\Vert$, which you don't know yet what $\Vert 1\Vert$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Using one part of Kouba answer to simplify my answer, let $x=b-c$, $y=c-a$, then
$$ \langle x,y\rangle=\Vert x\Vert\cdot\Vert y\Vert$$

But every inner product is written in this form: $\langle x,y\rangle=\lambda xy$,where $\lambda\gt 0$ and the norm induced by it is $\Vert x \Vert=|\lambda x|$, then we have:

$$(b-c)(c-a)=|\lambda||b-c||c-a|\ge 0$$

which implies

$b-c\ge 0$ and $c-a \ge 0$ or $b-c\le 0$ and $c-a\le 0$

The second one is absurd, so $b-c\ge 0$ and $c-a \ge 0$, and $c\in [a,b]$